# Old psychological fiction book: man with hypnosis abilities robs people through phone calls

Tags: story-identification, books

Looking for a book I have read something like twenty years ago.

There is a man who has hypnosis abilities uses his abilities who robs people using his abilities through phone calls.

Comment: Hi there. That's some info already, but still a bit terse... Maybe if you could take a look at [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, any recollection of the cover, of how the guy got his abilities, if he got caught for robbing people, what he was planning to do with the money?

Comment: On a similar note, I found myself wondering if the hypnotic guy was presented as the dangerous "villain" who had to be stopped, or as the "good guy" who was using his abilities in pursuit of some praiseworthy goal?

Comment: This is at least reminiscent of Fredric Brown's 'The Power' (1960). Although there, the phone calls are usually to tell people to drop dead!